# Cloning SSD to another SSD without having them connected to the mSATA connection simultaneously?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, clone

I’ve a SSD in my computer and I would like to clone my data and partitions on the new one.

The problem is that I only have one mSATA emplacement in my computer and I need to clone the SSD without having them connected simultaneously.

How could I achieve it easily?

PS: A HDD is also present in my computer, maybe I could use it as an intermediary?

Comment: Use a USB to mSATA converter.  You can't clone the SSD to the new SSD unless both devices are connected or you create a image of the SSD using the tool of your choice and storing the image on an internal/external storage.

Comment: So which tool can I use to create an image of my SSD and then restore it ?